# How to use jsoniter codegen with Android?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an Android app from scratch that will ingest JSON data from an HTTP API, convert to POJOs, and then utilize these POJOs throughout the app for various logic.

Because I'm starting from scratch, I did some research to figure out what I think is the best library to handle these API requests. Feel free to correct me if I'm ***entirely wrong***, because I had a lot of trouble finding more recent information, but it seems to me like [Retrofit is one of the faster libraries for doing this](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) (I know, it's a 2013 link, but I didn't find a lot of "recent" information on this subject)

Looking into Retrofit, it utilizes "converters" to parse the raw response text to a POJO. By default they include things like GSON, Jackson, Mochi, and several other things I haven't heard of. [Some further Googling suggests jsoniter is the fastest option](https://interviewbubble.com/performance-comparison-of-json-libraries-jackson-vs-gson-vs-fastjson-vs-json-simple-vs-jsonp/) (this is actually from 2018)

Looking around, I found someone who created [a converter for Retrofit that uses jsoniter](https://github.com/gmetal/retrofit-jsoniter) (last updated December 2017)

The README for this project mentions that the default decoding mode is `DecodingMode.REFLECTION_MODE`. Looking at [jsoniter's own docs on the subject](http://jsoniter.com/java-features.html#performance-is-optional), Reflection mode sounds like it's the ***slowest*** option. For performance they recommend either Dynamic Code Generation or Static Code Generation. After reading through their documentation on Static Code Generation, they provide a link to [an example for Android](https://github.com/json-iterator/java/tree/master/android-demo)

This demo was last updated December 2017, so it's not ***that*** old. But I can't seem to get the code to work in my own project. I copied the following to my `build.gradle` file (from their `build.gradle` file):

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompiler.finalizedBy(jsoniterStaticCodgen)
    }
}

task jsoniterStaticCodgen(type:JavaExec) {
    classpath configurations.getByName(android.sourceSets.main.compileConfigurationName)
    classpath project.buildDir.toString() + '/intermediates/classes/release'
    classpath project.buildDir.toString() + '/intermediates/classes/debug'
    main = 'com.jsoniter.static_codegen.StaticCodegen'
    args 'com.mycompany.myapplication.CodegenConfig'
    workingDir = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs[0].toString()
    standardOutput = System.out
    errorOutput = System.err
}
```

I then tried hitting the `Sync Now` button in Android Studio and was met with the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

What am I doing wrong?